# partial n-th sum of the infinity sequence and converging

Tags: real-analysis

I am suppose to find partial n-th sum of the infinity sequence and determine if it converge.

My sequence is $$  \sum_{ n=1}^{\infty} \ln \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right) $$

My solution is :

I find out that first terms are:$  \ln (2), \ln\frac{3}{2}, \ln \frac{4}{3} $

Then I wrote that: $ s_{n}=(\ln(2)+\ln(\frac{3}{2})+\ln\frac{4}{3}+...\ln(1+\frac{1}{n}) ) $

I know that, it is not enough, but I have no idea, what to do next, or if this is true.

Thanks a lot for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \ln(1+1/k)=\sum_{k=1}^n\ln\left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right) =\ln\prod_{k=1}^n \frac{k+1}{k} =\ln\frac{(n+1)!}{n!}=\ln(n+1)$$

Comment: I do not understand, why did you use factorial?

Comment: Because is the product of natural numbers from $n+1$ to 2 (in the numerator); and from $n$ to $1$ in the denominator..

Answer (score 0):

As $x\to 0,$

$$\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}= \frac{\ln(1+x)-\ln 1}{x-0}\to \ln'(1)=1.$$

This shows $[\ln(1+1/n)]/(1/n)\to 1.$ We know $\sum 1/n$ diverges, so by the limit comparison test, $\sum \ln(1+1/n)$ diverges.

Comment: More generally: if $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)\ne 0,$ then $\sum f(1/n)$ diverges.